# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null

Tags: java

I've got `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null` exception in my application two times,  both of them happened at `list.get()` method, the JDK source like this

```
 `private E get(Object[] paramArrayOfObject, int paramInt)
  {
    return paramArrayOfObject[paramInt];
  }
  `
```

What's the problem?
  please give some simple example which throws  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException null.`
  Thanks!

Comment: The answer is actually in the name of the exception. The array index is out of bounds. So there is no element at that index.

Comment: my guess is that you passed `paramInt` < 0

Comment: *both of them happened at list.get() method...* It usually happen at `.get()` calls only.

Comment: I think anyone new to programming both Null pointer exception and Array Out of Bound exception are different situation for them if anyone found duplicate then question must be closed with proper LINK..

Answer (score 1):

Please check array length before calling paramArrayOfObject[paramInt];

`if(paramArrayOfObject.length > paramInt) 
 return paramArrayOfObject[paramInt];
else
 return null;`

Comment: thanks,  but the code is from jdk source code, not my code and  if the index is out of the array range， it will throw java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:7 like this, not "null" .